# I am not getting how to do it for a case when we have to remove elements listed in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
function removeListedValues(arr) {
                var what, a = arguments, L = a.length, ax;
                while (L > 1 && arr.length) {
                    what = a[--L];
                    while ((ax= arr.indexOf(what)) !== -1) {
                        arr.splice(ax, 1);
                    }
                }
                return arr;
            }
```

`arr`: The given array

`without`: A list of elements which are to be removed from arr.
Return the array after removing the listed values.

Input:
arr: `[1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2]`
without: `[2, 3]`

Output:
`[1, 1]`

Comment: this is my code.. but i am not getting the outputs i am expecting

Comment: like for case of removeListedValues([1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2], [2, 3])...it should return [1,1]..but i am not getting the expected output

Comment: Use the `.filter()` method: `arr.filter(num => !without.includes(num));`

Answer (score 2):

To remove something in array, suggest using `.filter`

```js
const input = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2];
const without = [2, 3];

const result = input.filter(value => !without.includes(value))
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Set` (for faster lookup) from the array of values to exclude and use `Array#filter` along with `Set#has`.

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2], without = new Set([2, 3]);
const res = arr.filter(x => !without.has(x));
console.log(res);
```